# How to handle Form::checkbox in updating Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am struggling to update a certain model. The mode has the variable `'boolean_new_frame'`. This value could either be `0` or `1`. The configuration for the laravel form isn't working though. The code which I have now after doing some research keeps the value at `0`...

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('boolean_new_frame', 'Pagina openen in nieuw venster?') !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('boolean_new_frame', false) !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('boolean_new_frame', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function update($id) {
  $rule  = Model::findOrFail($id);
  $input = \Input::except(['true_mail_attachment']);

  $rule->update($input);

  return \Redirect::route('admin.rules')
    ->with('message', 'Good!');
}
```

Could someone help me adjust the form/controller that the '`boolean_new_frame'` variable is updated properly.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Sorry, using laravel 5.1

Comment: $checkbox = Input::get('boolean_new_frame');

Comment: @dsadnick and then `$rule['boolean_new_frame] = $checkbox`? because that isn't working..

Comment: Did you add the 'boolean_new_frame' to the fillable property on the model? `$fillable = ['boolean_new_frame']`?

Comment: Yes but I also added: `protected $casts = ['boolean_new_frame' => 'boolean'];` @NicklasKevinFrank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate with a default because when the checkbox is not checked there is no input entry for it:

Update (re-read the question):

```
$input["boolean_new_frame"] = !array_key_exists("boolean_new_frame",$input)?0:1;
$rule->update($input);
```

Comment: I tried this code and checked the box but the database still showed that the value is 0..

Comment: @AnnaJeanine I seem to have put it the wrong way around

Comment: I am now looking at your updated answer but i would like to keep the `"null"` in my form because that sets the default based on the selected item which the user wants to update.

Comment: and then keep the form like in my question?

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: Hmm.. it's still keeping the value at 0

Comment: @AnnaJeanine Sorry, I re-read the question. If I understand it correctly you need 0 if the checkbox is not checked and 1 if it is checked (the value of the checkbox will be null in that case?) So the updated code should do that... I hope.. if not then I give up.

Comment: no sorry. Looking back I did not very well describe that part. I need 1 when checked and 0 when unchecked/not checked.

Comment: thank you very much for putting your time into helping me!

Comment: It's working! Thank you so very very much for putting your precious free time into helping me fix my code! You're AWESOME!